# Direct method: differential equation with conditions on the first derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I would like to solve the following problem
\begin{equation}
u'' =u^3+\sin(x)^6 \quad u'(3)=6 \quad u'(6)=3.
\end{equation}
We can think the equation as a Euler-Lagrange equation associated to the Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
L(x,s,p)=\frac{1}{2}p^2+\frac{1}{4}s^4+s\sin^6(x)
\end{equation}
and we have the functional
\begin{equation}
F(u)=\int_3^6 (\frac{1}{2}(u'(x))^2+\frac{1}{4}u^4(x)+u(x)\sin^6(x))dx
\end{equation}
My idea was to work with in the sobolev space $H^{1,2}(3,6)$, wich I will call $\mathbb{X}$. I have choose as convergence notion the weak $L^2$ convergence on the derivatives and a strong convergence for the functions.
I proved that I can use some form of the Weierstrass Theorem to found a minimun(in $\mathbb{X}$), my question is how can I treat the conditions on the first derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by considering a different integral operator.
\begin{equation}
L(x,s,p)=\frac{1}{2}p^2+(x-9)p+\frac{1}{4}s^4+s(\sin(x)^6+1)
\end{equation}
The Euler-Lagrage equation is the same, but while integrating by part we obtain the wanted constraint for the derivative.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).